# Any way to change all UINavigationBar colors?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I need to change all of the navigation bar colors on an iphone app from a greenish color to dark grey, what is the easiest way to do this? Is there an easy way or do I have to go one by one? I have almost 100 views, and this would be extremely time consuming. Any help would be VERY much appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use the appearance API to set the color once on app startup?

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: NSDictionary *textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor darkGrayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions];
    textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor darkGrayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Appearance Proxy like this:

```
UINavigationBar *navBarAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearance];
navBarAppearance.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
```

Place this code somewhere t application launching sequence. It will set the tint color **of all instances of `UINavigationBar`** you create and even for existing ones (may need some redraw or what).

Calling `[<class> appearance]` on supported classes will return you special instance of that class (in fact it may be completely different class, but that doesn't matter). You may call methods on this instace **which are marked as Appearance Selectors**. In documentation they are often listed in section “Customizing the Appearance”. If you call any other method, you will probably encounter an exception.

This is extract from `UINavigationBar` docs with supported appearance methods:

> ### Customizing the Bar Appearance
>
> ```
>   tintColor
> – backgroundImageForBarMetrics:
> – setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:
> – titleVerticalPositionAdjustmentForBarMetrics:
> – setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:
>   titleTextAttributes
> ```

Many other classes supports this protocol.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but I am still a beginner, where would this code go so that it applies to all of the different views?

Comment: Basically anywhere, but I recommend `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: I extended my answer with more detailed info. It works like _theming_. You apply some global visual theme to whole application. This mechanism also supports more advanced things, like excluding some parts of your GUI from inheriting the global appearance, but that may be for another question.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `UIAppearance` it will let you change all future instances of a thing at once.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010906

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding this, but doesn't this require that code to be on every viewcontroller? How would I change this so I only have to write the code once? Would I have to view the plain XML or am I thinking of something completely different? Thank you!

Comment: In your app delegate's `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method you can make changes that will affect everything. It is basically the same as doing individual changes you just change from `[UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];` to `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`